# Insert record unless duplicate in which case change unique key column value and insert

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Spring-Boot application using Spring JdbcTemplate to perform database update on a MySql database.

Within the app I have a table that has a unique index made up of a number of columns e.g.

```
UserId,
Start_Date,
End_Date,
Sequence_Id
```

I'm trying to insert a record into the table, however, it is possible that the record may already exist but with a different status e.g. **"cancelled"** and/or **"withdrawn"**.

In this instance I wish to insert the record as a new record (not an update) but with an incremented `Sequence_Id`.

So, if the following record exists in the table:

```
UserId    | Start_Date    | End_Date    | Sequence_Id   | Status
1         | 01-01-2019    | 01-02-2019  | 1             | C
```

then if I try to insert the same record but with a status of A then I would expect this result:

```
1         | 01-01-2019    | 01-02-2019  | 2             | A
```

I'm looking for the the most efficient way of doing this. So, if for example two records already exist, then the `Sequence_Id` of the new record would need to be changed to 3 and then inserted.

In the vast majority of instances there will only ever be one record and so `Sequence_Id` will be 1 in over 90% of cases. It is possible though,(rare but not impossible) that there could be 2,3 or more records.

Because of the rarity of the situation it wouldn't seem efficient to perform a select prior to each insert. however, if a duplicate is found then I would need to find out the maximum `Sequence_Id` for that unique index before I can change the record and insert - does this mean I have no option but to perform an insert, select, insert in this situation or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: How about `insert`, catch the exception in Java, check if the SQLSTATE === `23000` (duplicate key error) and then insert again with incremented `Sequence_Id`? I think it's the cleanest solution, and if you return to that particular part of code in 5 years - it won't look alien or overly complex.

Comment: That is along the lines I was thinking. I guess that as it will be a rare occurrence, the chances of there being more than two `Sequence_Id`s  for a given key will be even less likely.  In which case I'm probably better retrying the insert with `Sequence_Id` = 2 etc rather than selecting the max `Sequence_Id for the index?

Comment: You're right, since you're dealing with a rare occurrence - there's no need to overcomplicate it. You know the best since it's the system you look after, but I'd say you'd be fine with what you described.

Comment: I feel compelled to share this discussion https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222. If I were implementing this, my inclination would be to create a stored procedure to handle such a task.